# Right sidebar as a template in joomla

Tags: html, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I am working on a two column template in joomla 2.5. I want to make it as three column with an addition of right sidebar only on the front page and rest of the pages only two columns (Left side and content area).

I did the necessary changes in index.php, css, xml files and created a right sidebar. But it affected all the pages. Should I create a separate template for the right sidebar or download any extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this by admin panel.

Go to extensions->module manager

Choose one of the menu module types (I choose 'Menu example')

Enable it

Choose position

scroll down, actually second page, choose position-6, which is Beez5 or Beez_20 top right.

Make sure the menu is enabled for all pages that you want it to be.

Save and close.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way

```
<?php $menu = JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) 
{
?>
    <div class="frontend_container">
    <div class="column1"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="module1"/></div>
    <div class="column2"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="module2"/></div>
    <div class="column3"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="module3"/></div>
   </div>
<?php } 
else {
?><div class="frontend_container">
    <div class="column1"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="module4"/></div>
    <div class="column2"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="module5"/></div>
```

Comment: Hi Pramod i gave this code in index.php changing the div class accordingly, i specified the php parameters in params.php. Its not stil working. I dont know where i missed out..

Comment: You can call module within these divs...i have edited the answer

Comment: Hi, your code is working good !! but the problem with my template is my content area has a fixed width of 744px. So the leftside module gets loaded, then a big gap followed by rightside module, content area gets below the both area. If i sepcify a width lesser of about 544px it gets in the gap, and resembles a 3 column template. But the  inner pages are of 2 column with a blank space on its right side

Comment: You have to manage the total width in both the cases..its just a matter of css. In the frontend you have to manage the width in 3 column and in inner page you need to divide the width in 2 column.

Comment: This is my code in index.php for the main content area           <div id="colmain" >
            <jdoc:include type="message" />
           <div id="component">
                 <jdoc:include type="component"  />
            </div>   The style for content area is "#colmain", it reflects in all the pages .. how to show the difference between the main and inner pages by changing the style ?